# How to assign a known number of different size of outbound packages, to a known (different) number of inbound deliveries?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming, matching-theory

I am trying to solve a problem that looks like the multiple knapsack problem, the multiple bin packing problem and the subset-sum problem, but isn't exactly one of them.

Imagine a warehouse where 4 deliveries of different quantities (2208, 1920, 400, 1120) arrived at different times. From those boxes 39 "subpackages" of different quantities were taken (these quantities are smaller, see table below) and sent out.

**How can we link each outbound package, to one of the inbound deliveries? And/or how is this type of problem called (so I can research further)?**
There is at least one solution I found manually for the example below. However, I want some strategies that I can put into code, so I can apply this to other similar cases.
So I am looking to do this programatically with heuristics and/or with analytical optimization with a certain objective function (eg. minimal time difference between outbound 'groups').

Constraints:

- The total quantity delivered equals the total quantity sent out.
- The outbound packages cannot be divided
- A departure cannot be linked to an arrival that occurs at a later timestamp. Meaning "we can not send out what has not arrived" (time-constraint)

Compared with other known problems:

- This is the multiple knapsacks problem but with all items values = 0 and different size knapsacks
- This is the multiple bin problem but with fixed number of bins of different sizes and the bin must be filled completely
- This is the subset sum problem, but with multiple non-overlapping subsets to be found
- This is the number partition problem, but with fixed number of partitions and the sum of the partitions should not be equal to each other.

Here's the example table (the 4 deliveries are at index 1,3,6,9; the rest are the outbound packages):

| index | TIMESTAMP | DELIVERY | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1614355831 | Inbound | 2208 |
| 2 | 1614355831 | Departure | 400 |
| 3 | 1614355833 | Inbound | 1920 |
| 4 | 1617200107 | Departure | 720 |
| 5 | 1617804783 | Departure | 520 |
| 6 | 1618562403 | Inbound | 400 |
| 7 | 1618926163 | Departure | 118 |
| 8 | 1618930180 | Departure | 160 |
| 9 | 1619169080 | Inbound | 1120 |
| 10 | 1619170760 | Departure | 84 |
| 11 | 1619450233 | Departure | 120 |
| 12 | 1619525526 | Departure | 240 |
| 13 | 1619768362 | Departure | 80 |
| 14 | 1619770192 | Departure | 40 |
| 15 | 1620058521 | Departure | 160 |
| 16 | 1620061855 | Departure | 3 |
| 17 | 1620135685 | Departure | 120 |
| 18 | 1620139836 | Departure | 200 |
| 19 | 1620144816 | Departure | 2 |
| 20 | 1620232806 | Departure | 1 |
| 21 | 1620373216 | Departure | 240 |
| 22 | 1620375018 | Departure | 40 |
| 23 | 1620663042 | Departure | 40 |
| 24 | 1620742517 | Departure | 120 |
| 25 | 1620744519 | Departure | 280 |
| 26 | 1620744525 | Departure | 50 |
| 27 | 1620835864 | Departure | 1 |
| 28 | 1620922242 | Departure | 1 |
| 29 | 1620977846 | Departure | 280 |
| 30 | 1621268120 | Departure | 80 |
| 31 | 1621347504 | Departure | 280 |
| 32 | 1621347512 | Departure | 80 |
| 33 | 1621582717 | Departure | 120 |
| 34 | 1621584500 | Departure | 80 |
| 35 | 1621874565 | Departure | 240 |
| 36 | 1621952070 | Departure | 80 |
| 37 | 1621953896 | Departure | 240 |
| 38 | 1621961031 | Departure | 1 |
| 39 | 1621961035 | Departure | 1 |
| 40 | 1621961046 | Departure | 1 |
| 41 | 1622187496 | Departure | 120 |
| 42 | 1622189393 | Departure | 120 |
| 43 | 1622533239 | Departure | 185 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this as a [Generalized Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem), where the departures are the items and the arrivals are the bins.  Here, $w_{ij}=\text{QUANTITY}_j$ for items, and $t_i=\text{QUANTITY}_i$ for bins.  Your third constraint corresponds to fixing $x_{ij}=0$ (or just omitting the variable) when the timestamp of bin $i$ is later than the timestamp of item $j$.

One approach is to take $p_{ij}=\text{QUANTITY}_j$ and accept the resulting optimal solution only if the objective value is $\sum_j \text{QUANTITY}_j$.

Alternatively, use a constant $0$ objective function and replace the $\le$ constraints with $=$.